# redirect url with question mark after url rewriting in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm looking for a pattern to do the right redirection after an url rewriting

```
test/14/optional-string-not-important?edit=ok
```

should redirect towards

```
test.php?id=14&edit=ok
```

...after url rewriting,
I've made a rule like:

```
RewriteRule    ^test/([0-9]+)(/([a-z0-9,\.-]*))?(\?(.*))?$    test.php?id=$1&$5
```

but the question mark in (\?(.*)) doesn't want to escape I don't know why...
any idea?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't match `QUERY_STRING` in `RewriteRule`. Since you're just attempting to preserve existing query string you can just use `QSA` flag. `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.

Try this rule instead:

```
RewriteRule ^test/([0-9]+)(/|$) test.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks! I've modified to RewriteRule ^test/([0-9]+)(/(.+))?$  /test.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA] in order empty string (as optional) after test/14 doesn't send me to not found page... and it did the trick!

Comment: Made a minor edit in order to make text after `/test/14` as optional. Please check.